# how to break line in ionic 2 elements like buttons

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

i have a few buttons in my app's screen and i want use Icon and below of that, write the title of the button...

in ionic 2 i can't use "< br>" or h1,h2 or even display block for this purpose.

code:

```
<button primary>
     <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
     Calendar
</button>
```

i tried like this:

```
<button primary>
     <h1>
         <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
     </h1>
     <br />
     <h2>
         Calendar
     </h2>
</button>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found a solution... Thank you [Justin Willis](https://github.com/jgw96)

Instead of using extra html inside your button you can actually achieve this with just a touch of css. You can simply change the button-inner class to have a flex-flow of column. So you could just use something like this

```
.button-inner {
  flex-flow: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Ionic 4 & 5 you can do this with a div:

```
<ion-button primary>
   <div>
      <h1>
         <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
      </h1>
      <h2>
         Calendar
      </h2>
    </div>
</ion-button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You wont have a choice but to use sass. I'm not answering your  question but are you sure you want it this way ??

You can do it this way ?

```
<button large >
    <ion-icon name='home' class="breakme"></ion-icon>
    Home
</button>
```

Or you can have lists with onclicks `(click)="calendar"` and fake it with a list?

```
<ion-list no-lines>
    <ion-item (click)="getData()">
        <ion-icon name="leaf"></ion-icon>
        <br />
        Herbology 
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item (click)="getData()">
        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
        <br />
        Calander
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```